# "Invalid column name"-error on Insert-Select with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 
SELECT *
FROM table_2 S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT column1
                  FROM table_1 T
                  WHERE T.column1 = S.column1)
```

When I run this script I get get an

> invalid column name column1

on the first line even though the column does exist for each table.

I am trying to insert into one table from another where they have different `column1` values (`column1` is the primary key). Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Does the `select` work without the `insert`?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example script?  We are having to take your word that the columns match in both tables.

Comment: sheesh Tim, get it right the first time already.   : )

Comment: Try to specify the column names explicitly: `INSERT INTO table_1(column1,column2,column3)SELECT SomeColumn1,SomeColumn2,SomeColumn3 FROM table_2 S WHERE ....`

Comment: The select does not work without the insert. I tried specifying the columns explicity and that gave the same error as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database? `USE DatabaseName`

Comment: I tried have the USE Database name and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place you are using two SQL antipatterns in your statement. Fix them and your error will likely clear up.

First, never use an insert without specifying the columns you want to insert to. You can get some hard to track down error with this type of thing if people switch columns  in the table later on.

Second there is no excuse for ever using Select * in production code especially in an insert. Your code will break if anyone ever adds a column or removes a column form this table.

It is possible that part of your problem has to do with a column mismatch between the tables or that you have a column that is an identity which cannot be inserted into.

Comment: I tried putting in the columns explicitly but I got the same error for each column. What identities can not be inserted into?

Comment: Identity columns are ones where the value is autogenerated which is why they can't be inserted into. They are usually the id column and PK. Please post the exact statement you are using now and the exact error received from SQL Server in your question. It is hard to help you without seeing those things.